# Rellenar con ceros intercalados matriz en python

Tags: python, bucles, padding, itertools

Supongamos las matrices A y B:

```
    |1 2 3|     |1 2 3|
A = |4 5 6| B = |4 5 6|
    |7 8 9|     |7 8 9|
```

Realizo un .flatten() sobre ellas y formo una nueva matriz:

```
C = |1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9|
    |1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9|
```

Ahora, quiero rellenar esta nueva matriz con ceros intercalados entre cada columna y fila (también al final de la fila), obteniendo la matriz D como:

```
Nótese que los 4 ceros que hay seguidos se corresponden al de la última 
columna de cada fila y la separación con ceros entre las filas

D = |1 0 2 0 3 0 0 0 0 4 0 5 0 6 0 0 0 0 7 0 8 0 9 0|
    |1 0 2 0 3 0 0 0 0 4 0 5 0 6 0 0 0 0 7 0 8 0 9 0|
```

¿Existe alguna forma optima de realizar esto sin bucles en python? ¿merece la pena mirar su implementación con Swig o cPython? Este proceso se ha de realizar siempre para adaptar la señal de entrada, por lo que es importante su optimización al máximo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con numpy, se puede emplear una array de indices para solo poner valores en las posiciones de estos indices.

Por ejemplo:

```py
import numpy as np

p = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
ind = [2, 4, 5]  # lista de indices para cambiar
p [ind] = [-1, -1, -1]  # cambia posiciones 2, 4 y 5 a -1
print(p)  # [ 1  2 -1  4 -1 -1  7  8  9 10]
```

Para ir lo más rápido, `ind` tendría que ser una `np.array` de tipo `int_` (el tipo nativo para indices, depende si numpy seria 32 bit o 64).

Una array así se puede emplear para rellenar `d`. Se calcula las posiciones donde va cada elemento de `a`. Eso solo hay que hacer una sola vez. El array `d` hay que inicializar con ceros. Si este array `d` no se cambia dentro del bucle, también solo hay que inicializarla una sola vez.

Aquí el código. Las matrices `a` y `b` están cambiado para asegurar que también funciona correctamente con matrices no cuadradas.

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(1, 13).reshape(3, 4)
b = np.arange(31, 43).reshape(3, 4)
print(a)
print(b)

m, n = a.shape
ind = np.array([j*2 + (2*n+3)*i for i in range(m) for j in range(n)], dtype=np.int_)
# print(ind)
d = np.zeros(shape=(2, m*n*2 + 3*(m-1)), dtype=a.dtype)

d[0, ind] = a.flatten()
d[1, ind] = b.flatten()

print(d)
```

Resultado:

```
# a
[[ 1  2  3  4]
 [ 5  6  7  8]
 [ 9 10 11 12]]
# b
[[31 32 33 34]
 [35 36 37 38]
 [39 40 41 42]]
# d
[[ 1  0  2  0  3  0  4  0  0  0  0  5  0  6  0  7  0  8  0  0  0  0  9  0 10  0 11  0 12  0]
 [31  0 32  0 33  0 34  0  0  0  0 35  0 36  0 37  0 38  0  0  0  0 39  0 40  0 41  0 42  0]]
```

PD: Aquí hay otra manera para calcular `ind`, más típico para numpy. En teoría seria más rápido para arrays muy grandes.

```
ind = np.arange(0, 2*m*n, 2, dtype=np.int_) + np.repeat(np.arange(0, 3*m, 3, dtype=np.int_), n)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Es justo lo que buscaba!!